# Index absent from `possible_keys`… but only on some environments

Tags: mysql

I have a software stack which I run myself, but also deploy to customer premises.

There is a particular query which runs very well in my environment, but runs terribly in the customer's environment.

I have confirmed using `EXPLAIN` that *my environment*'s query planner sees that there is a great index available (and uses it). Whereas the same query in the *customer's environment* does not offer that index under `possible_keys`.

---

Here's the full query, somewhat anonymized:

```sql
SELECT t0.*,
       t1.*,
       t2.*,
       t3.value
FROM   table0 t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
             ON t0.id = t1.table0_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
             ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
            AND t2.deleted = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
             ON t0.id = t3.table0_id
            AND t3.type = 'whatever'
WHERE t0.business IN ('workcorp')
AND '2016-11-01 00:00:00' <= t0.date
AND t0.date < '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY t0.date DESC
```

The stage where our environments differ is on `JOIN`ing to `table3`. So theoretically you can ignore a large amount of the query and think of it like this:

```sql
SELECT t0.*
       t3.value
FROM   table0 t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
             ON t0.id = t3.table0_id
            AND t3.type = 'whatever'
```

---

Both of our environments' query plans agree on how to `JOIN` to `t1` and to `t2`. But they differ in their plan for how to `JOIN` to `t3`.

My environment correctly identifies two possible indexes for `JOIN`ing to `t3`, and correctly identifies that `table0_id` is the best choice for this query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type |      possible_keys       |    key    | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | ref  | table0_id,type_and_value | table0_id |     108 | func |     2 | 100.00   | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

The customer's environment *does not consider the index `table0_id` to be an option*, and falls back to `type_and_value` (which is a really bad choice):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  |       key      | key_len |  ref  | rows           | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | ref  | type_and_value | type_and_value | 257     | const | (far too many) |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+----------------+----------+-------------+
```

---

What happens if we `FORCE INDEX`?

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT t0.*,
       t1.*,
       t2.*,
       t3.value
FROM   table0 t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
             ON t0.id = t1.table0_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
             ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
            AND t2.deleted = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 FORCE INDEX (table0_id)
             ON t0.id = t3.table0_id
            AND t3.type = 'whatever'
WHERE t0.business IN ('workcorp')
AND '2016-11-01 00:00:00' <= t0.date
AND t0.date < '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY t0.date DESC
```

On my environment, I got:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |    key    | key_len | ref  | rows |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | ref  | table0_id     | table0_id |     108 | func |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Compared to my original query plan (which proposed *two* `possible_keys`): this narrowed down the choice to just one.

But the customer got a different result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | (loads) |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Adding the `FORCE INDEX` narrows down the customer's `possible_keys` from one bad choice, to *no* choices.

---

So why is it that the customer's environment does not have the same indexes available in `possible_keys`? Naturally I was given to suspect "maybe they *don't* have that index". So we did a `SHOW INDEXES FROM table3`. Here's my environment (for comparison):

```
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique |    Key_name     | Seq_in_index |   Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table3 |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id              | A         |       16696 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table3 |          1 | table0_id       |            1 | table0_id       | A         |       16696 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table3 |          1 | type_and_value  |            1 | type            | A         |          14 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table3 |          1 | type_and_value  |            2 | value           | A         |        8348 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Their environment had the same index, `table0_id` available:

```
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality       | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table3 |          1 | table0_id       |            1 | table0_id       | A         | (same as PRIMARY) |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I was also careful to ask "is this a slave? is the master the same?": they assured me that all instances had this index, as required.

---

So I thought "maybe the index is broken in some way?" And proposed that they do the very simplest query relying upon that index:

```sql
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT *
FROM table3
WHERE table0_id = 'whatever'
```

In *this* case: their environment behaved the same as mine (and correctly), proposing the use of the index `table0_id`:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys |    key    | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered |         Extra         |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table3 | ref  | table0_id     | table0_id |     108 | const |    1 | 100.00   | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

So they definitely *have* that index. And their query planner *can* recognise that it is eligible for use (for some queries at least).

---

What's going on here? Why is `table0_id` ineligible for use on certain queries, but *only on the customer's environment*? Could it be that the index is broken in some way? Or that the query planner is making a mistake?

Are there any other tests I can do to figure out why it's not using the index for this query?

Comment: don't abstract too much the query from your customers premises. Details are important in this case.

Comment: the only simplification I have done of the query here is to rename columns and tables (for anonymity), and (for brevity and anonymity) to expand the selected columns from each table to wildcards (where before they selected a variety of specific columns). I think this should be equivalent. I do appreciate that details are important, but I have to be careful, as the customer has stringent security requirements.

Comment: It occurs to me — although the customer has the same _indexes_ as I do — maybe their schema is subtly different. Like maybe `table0_id` is a different datatype, encoding or collation in their environment, in some significant way that makes it ineligible for a `JOIN`. I will ask them for a `DESCRIBE` of t0 and of t3.

Comment: If your advice was with respect to my filtering of query _results_: I agree that I have omitted some details, but I submit that I have included all the parts that show relevant corroboration or difference.

Comment: No no, I meant, the query coming right after `So theoretically you can ignore a large amount of the query and think of it like this` seems incomplete - no t1 nor t2 tables are present

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I provided that stripped-down query as an attempt at a "minimal example". I know that the `JOIN` on `t3`  is the environment-sensitive part in the full query, so — to help the reader see the problem— I presented a shorter query which _only_ contains the problematic part (and _intentionally_ omits the parts which appear to be unrelated). That said: you are right to say that it may be unwise to assume that this smaller query reproduces the problem. Ideally I need to get the customer to `EXPLAIN` the smaller query, to know whether I can use it as a representative example.

Comment: Before we continue, I have 2 questions. (a) is the query actually slow at your customers? (b) is there any record in his database satisfying `'2016-11-01 00:00:00' <= t0.date
AND t0.date < '2016-12-01 00:00:00'`?

Comment: @Sebas: (a) the query takes multiple hours on the customer site, whereas it takes <1sec on my environment. I have reason to believe that the sizes of our datasets are similar orders of magnitude. I fully believe that the difference in speed is due to the difference in the index used. The `ref` `JOIN` type is [best when `rows` is small](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_ref), and the `table0_id` index achieves this (`rows=2`), but in the customer's environment, it chooses `type_and_value`, which has `rows=(very very many)`.

Comment: @Sebas: (b) the customer indeed has records satisfying that date range. narrowing the date range cuts down the query time. the date range they search seems to effectively cover "all time" for their dataset, so they could consider removing the date constraint entirely. but since the problem appears to be with the performance of the `JOIN` on `t3` rather than the date filter on `t0`: I suspect this might not be the source of the performance concern.

Comment: are you using innodb?

Comment: @Sebas certainly I am using InnoDB in my environment. I _assume_ the customer's environment is the same, but I have left a question for them in order to confirm this. if one of their tables used a storage engine other an InnoDB: could that explain why the index is not being used?

Comment: Well no, or at least it depends which table. I asked this question because I believe myisam requires you to rebuild index statistics, while innodb does that on the fly. There's definitely one last thing you could test at least: `CHECK TABLE table3;CHECK TABLE table1;CHECK TABLE table2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the charsets (and/or the collations).

I used this query to reveal the charset in each environment:

```sql
SELECT table_name, column_name, character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_schema = "my_cool_database"
  AND table_name IN ("t0", "t3")
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2
```

And for bonus points I checked the character collation in each environment:

```sql
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM t0;
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM t3;
```

In my environment: all columns in both tables had `utf8` charset and `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.

In the customer's environment: `t0` matched my environment exactly, yet `t3` was a unique snowflake; its columns had `latin1` charset and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.

---

So, what we were seeing is that the index that existed on `t3.table0_id` (a `latin1` column) could *not* be used to `JOIN` to a `utf8` table. Hence the index worked fine for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table3
WHERE table0_id = 'whatever'
```

Yet the index could *not* be used for:

```sql
SELECT
t0.id,
t3.value
FROM t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3
```

Similar symptoms are described on the [Percona blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/10/21/join-performance-charsets/), [John Watson's blog](https://watson-net.com/blog/character-set-hell/) and [Baron Schwartz's blog](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2012/08/20/why-wont-mysql-use-the-best-index-in-a-join/).